# How to build a custom tooltip window using bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, popover

I am trying my hands on building websites. I want to have a functionality like [Established User On Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) When website visitor hovers mouse over a picture of user who answered the question, the new window(may be tooltip/popover- I am not sure) should be opened, having all the details about that user and leaving the new window(mouse out) it should get hidden. How to achieve this same thing using bootstrap customization?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself so far?

Comment: I've got what i wanted. This helped me very much

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13192515/looking-for-a-mouseover-feature-like-stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

You should really post some code you've tried, before asking a question, but, as a suggestion:

This can be easily achieved with CSS. Let's say we have two elements: #wrapper and #popup.

#wrapper contains the image, the #popup element and has position:relative.

#popup is the element that contains the user data, is hidden, has position:absolute and top:100%. You can play with this to achieve different positions for the popup.

To make the #popup visibile you can set a CSS :hover condition on #wrapper to display the popup, something like

```
#wrapper:hover #popup { display:block; }
```

Here's a fiddle to show the concept: http://jsfiddle.net/8f68G/

Hope this helps.